# Reactive value doesn't update when it should

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new into Shiny and I think I don't understand some basic principle. How to make my variables update?

Both variable1 and output$added are reactive so why they don't change on the screen after pushing the button and how to make them change?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    textInput("inserted", "Insert a number"),
    textOutput("written"),
    textOutput("added"),
    actionButton("button1", "Push me")
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   variable1 <- reactive({
     as.numeric(input$inserted)
   })

   assign15tovar <- function() {
     variable1 <<- reactive({
       15
     })
   }

   observeEvent(input$button1, {
     assign15tovar()
   })

   output$written <- variable1
   output$added <- reactive({
     variable1() + 10
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code is just an example of my problem in my actual app, but solving this should help.

Comment: This is not at all how reactive values are meant to work. Take a look at [reactiveValues](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html) instead. Also maybe check out these introductions to shiny reactive programming to get a better sense of what's going on: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/

Comment: There is no way to do it without creating a list and referring to my variables with $? Btw I thought x <- reactive({...}) is equivalent to x <- reactiveValues({...}), isn't it?

Comment: Well, you could just use [reactiveVal](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/reactiveVal.html) rather than a list. But then you don't assign/update with `<-`, you use `myvar(newval)`. But `reactive()` isn't the same as `reactiveVal()` or `reactiveValues()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way to get the behavior you want

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  variable1 <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$inserted, {
    variable1(as.numeric(input$inserted))
  })

  assign15tovar <- function() {
    variable1(15)
  }

  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    assign15tovar()
  })

  output$written <- renderText({variable1()})
  output$added <- renderText({variable1() + 10})
}
```

Normally you can't manually set values of reactive elements, so you need a `reactiveVal` specifically which allows you to set it's value. In this case `variable1()` returns the current value and `variable1(newval)` will set a new value. And then in this case we need to observe the text box for changes.

And note that your output statements were not correct. Normally you need some type of `render()` function. You generally don't assign to them directly.